# Google Cloud Compute Engine: sudo broke after "dnf upgrade" on Centos 8

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openssl, google-compute-engine, sudo

the company i'm working with is developing a web application based on Laravel Framework, using Google Cloud Platform infrastructures. The frontend VM is a Centos8 OS with Apache webserver installed.
Seems that a developer ran a pretty massive "dnf upgrade" which included: kernel, openssl ,kerberos and others packages.
After the upgrade, seems that ldconfig has lost his mind:

```
[developer@webserver ~]$ sudo su - root
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 19 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: unable to load /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so: /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: EVP_md4, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

same for other commands like "dnf" or "rpm":

```
[developer@webserver ~]$ rpm
rpm: symbol lookup error: /lib64/librpmio.so.8: undefined symbol: EVP_md2, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
```

after a little bit of investigations, i found that the same commands, specifing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, are working:

```
[developer@webserver ~]$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64 rpm
RPM version 4.14.3
Copyright (C) 1998-2002 - Red Hat, Inc.
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL
...
```

...of course, i can't do the same trick with "sudo" command.

Important fact is that the VM is still running and it was never rebooted ( i'll exaplin later why i'm sayin this )

( and finally..at the point )
The major problem is that we can't use root account cause "sudo" is not working and, by default, Google use Public Key Authentication as deafult method (Local users has random passwords genereated by GCP). So actually, i can't even do a "dnf reinstall" to try fix the issues

I was afraid that, once rebooted, every services stops to work because of the incorrect dependecies library path, so instead of doing a reboot, i have created an image based on the VM and then a new VM based on that image.
As i was thinking: Once booted the new VM, every services stopped working. i was able to read the logs over the serial console of GCP web interface.

a snippet:

```
...
Oct 27 20:20:30 webserver google_oslogin_nss_cache[783]: /usr/bin/google_oslogin_nss_cache: /lib64/libjson-c.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/google_oslogin_nss_cache)
Oct 27 20:20:30 webserver NetworkManager[778]: /usr/sbin/NetworkManager: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: EVP_md4, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
Oct 27 20:20:30 webserver google_oslogin_nss_cache[783]: /usr/bin/google_oslogin_nss_cache: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: EVP_md4, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
Oct 27 20:20:30 webserver sssd[771]: ldb: unable to dlopen /usr/lib64/ldb/modules/ldb/ldap.so : /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: EVP_md4, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
...
```

Using Google official documentation, i found the "startup-script" section of the VM properties that can be launched at every boot and that can be used to "change" user's passwords.
I know that, by default, all VMs has root access disabled, so i made this and added to vm's "automation" script:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo 'developer:PASSWORD' | chpasswd
echo 'root:PASSWORD' | chpasswd
```

Once rebooted, i've tried to login using the "serial console" option on the web interface, but with no luck. I've also used journalctl ( as normal user ) to find something in the logs... but nothing.
i suppose that is a consequence of that "google_oslogin_nss_cache" error
there's no way to run that script.

Searching on the internet, i've found some posts where someone was able to login directly as "root" using the "gcloud compute ssh" command. So i have tried to login as described using another VM of the same project, using both my google account user and root user...but also in this way ...no luck.
( i forgot to mention that my google account has "project owner" role, so actually i have all necessary permissions )

is there another way to reset "root" password without using "sudo" or i have to reinstall the VM from start?

I'm sorry for the long explanation....hope that everything is clear

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... actually this question is divided by 2 different issues:

1. The only possible way for me to recover "root" account was to stop the VM, detach the boot disk, mount the boot disk on a new VM, mount the filesystem and modify the user. once boot disk is reattached to the original VM..you can use the modified account
2. second issue was made by upgrading openssl...so in the end the only way to avoid that error messages was to create a new file: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf:

> ```
> /usr/lib64
> ```